# Section responsivity problems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a problem with a responsivity of one of my sections.

http://apts.apartment.cz/travel-test/index.html

Sorry, the website is in Czech but I'm sure you will get it. It is the one below **"REZERVUJTE SI"** **H2**. Under 1200px the buttons are not aligned. Under 992px the buttons extend to the picture below. And under 768px there is the same problem.

I'm sure there is a simple solution but I just can't figure it out. If you can, I will be more than happy.

Thank you again for all your tips!

Radim

Comment: I would give a `min-height` to the <p> element.
like `min-height: 90px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this code on your bottom of the `styleSheet` this will fix your issue

```
@media(max-width:1200px){
    .col-md-3.col-sm-6.text-center > p { 
        min-height: 85px;
    }
    a.button_intro, .button_intro {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
}   
@media(max-width:767px){
    .col-md-3.col-sm-6.text-center > p { 
        min-height: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tick the answer If it's useful

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `min-height` or `height` in your css for this paragraph on those resolutions. A way to achieve this is adding a class to your paragraph and make a `min-height: 80px;` inside that class.

Answer (score 0):

For `button`, you need to add some `margin-bottom` value. Then buttons extend to the picture issue will getting fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you noticed that when `width > 1200px` the number of text lines for all paragraphs will be the same (which is Three lines) so all containers will be aligned and with the same height but when `width < 1200px` the number of text lines for paragraphs will differs depending on the paragraph length and this will affect the whole container height, so the best thing to do is adding `min-height:90px` or any `px` you want to `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you for desktop view, Will working fine for huge amount of content height. You need to add class .flex-row and .flex-col and .post as per the following method.

```css
.flex-row{
display:flex;
}
.flex-col{
flex:1;
position:relative;
padding-bottom:45px;
}
.post {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row flex-row">
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center flex-col">
      <p>
       <a href="https://www.booking.com/country/gr.html?aid=1324331&amp;label=gr" target="_blank"><img src="img/hotely_800.jpg" alt="Pic" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </p>
      <h4>Hotely</h4>
      <p>
       Vybírejte si z hotelů, apartmánů, vil, hostelů, penzionů i dalších typů ubytování v Řecku za nejlepší ceny!
      </p>
                        <div class="post"><a href="https://www.booking.com/country/gr.html?aid=1324331&amp;label=gr" target="_blank" class="animated fadeInUp button_intro">Najít hotely</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center flex-col">
      <p>
       <a href="http://letenky.kralovna.cz/booking/index.jsp?id_dealer=5551" target="_blank"><img src="img/letenky_800.jpg" alt="Pic" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </p>
      <h4>Letenky</h4>
      <p>
       Potřebujete levné letenky do Řecka? Není nic jednoduššího než si vybrat z nabídky našich renomovaných partnerů!
      </p>
                        <div class="post"><a href="http://letenky.kralovna.cz/booking/index.jsp?id_dealer=5551" target="_blank" class="animated fadeInUp button_intro">Najít letenky</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center flex-col">
      <p>
       <a href="https://dovolena.invia.cz/recko/?aid=4282530" target="_blank"><img src="img/zajezdy_800.jpg" alt="Pic" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </p>
      <h4>Zájezdy</h4>
      <p>
       Pokud neradi cestujete na vlastní pěst, vyberte si jeden ze zájezdů do Řecka za skvělé ceny!
      </p>
                      <div class="post">  <a href="https://dovolena.invia.cz/recko/?aid=4282530" target="_blank" class="animated fadeInUp button_intro">Najít zájezdy</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center flex-col">
      <p>
       <a href="http://www.rentalcars.com?affiliateCode=e_travel_cz" target="_blank"><img src="img/auto_800.jpg" alt="Pic" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </p>
      <h4>Půjčení auta</h4>
      <p>
       Pokud si chcete užít bezstarostnou dovolenou a poznat destinaci se vším všudy, podívejte se na nabídku autopůjčoven!
      </p>
                     <div class="post">   <a href="http://www.rentalcars.com?affiliateCode=e_travel_cz" target="_blank" class="animated fadeInUp button_intro">Najít auta</a></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```